# How to create a Wordpress User Profile when creating a Membership with Civi?

Tags: wordpress, user

I am using WP 4.8.1 and CiviCRM 4.7.22

I would like to know what steps I need to take to ensure that when someone contributes through a civiCRM contribution page a Wordpress user profile with access to restricted pages is created?

Does this require an extension?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require users (or give the option) to create a WordPress user account in the advanced settings in the settings of the profile used on the membership contribution page.

You will have to check the box 'Anyone can register' in the WordPress general settings. I would also recommend installing a recaptcha plugin for user signups to prevent a large number on user accounts being created by bots.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and that option is already selected to required.  I assume they cannot create the account until the transaction has been completed.  Am I correct?   I have done some test membership creations and I didn't receive any information about my wp profile.  How is that delivered?

Comment: What you should see is a area inserted into your form that states an account is required. It will provide a link to login if they already have an account. If not they can check if a user name is available and then enter a user name and password. If you don't see this added to your form check that the 'Anyone can register' box is checked in the WordPress general settings. Also if you are logged in this info will not show. The account is created when the transaction is submitted. When complete the user will be automatically logged in.

Comment: I see that now.  I had no idea as I did not have  Anyone can register enabled.  That will solve most of the issues. Thank you. I still need to run some live tests on it. I am not sure if the created WP Username will be stored in Civi's membership dashboard also and how to create usernames for the Civi Memberships we already have so I can sych them with WP. I am willing to create usernames manually if there is field for it in the dashboard that will map to WP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate your CiviCRM database with the data gained from a profile, then I think you would have to set up the profile within CiviCRM by going to /Administer/Customize Data and Screens/Profiles and link the profile you create to your contribution page.

You can synchronise your users in WordPress to contacts in CiviCRM databases by going to Administer/Users and Permissions/Synchronize Users to Contacts.  I haven't used it myself but there is also an extension at https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-wordpress-profile-sync to synchronize WordPress user profile in sync with the corresponding fields of a CiviCRM contact. The synchronisation takes place regardless of whether the changes are made in WordPress or CiviCRM.

If you wish to restrict certain pages in WordPress (such as the contribution page) to logged in users in WordPress, you could use a WordPress plug-in such as WordPress Action Control (see link here http://brandonwamboldt.ca/plugins/members-only-menu-plugin/. )

A good WordPress plug-in I can recommend for Login and registration is Profile Builder at https://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/.  There is a free version and a pro version.

There is some useful information on setting up Profiles in CiviCRM in the CiviCRM User Guide at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, I need to do the opposite of this. I want civi contributors to create a wordpress profile.   We offer memberships with Civi.  When want our members to have access to private pages on Wordpress.  So when they create their membership with civi, it needs to create a wordpress profile as well that will allow them access to the private areas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) plugin to achieve this. Set up instructions can be found on the plugin's page.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed this, but I have some questions about it I hope you can answer.  1. It is set to create a WP user profile when a civimembership is created, but it uses their full name (Mr.-John-Doe). Is there a way we can get it to display only the first name as default.  These users will have access to the private forum and I don't think they are going to be comfortable showing their full names. 2.  After the CiviMembership is created, how does the members know about his WP User Profile and where to login to it?  Is an automatic email with an activate link sent out?

Comment: There are hooks throughout the plugin that allow you to customise how it behaves. See for example https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync/issues/16